# Calcular Preço em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma tabela onde serão calculados Quantidade x Preço em javascript. Seguindo a regra das casas decimais.

No momento estou utilizando a função básica, porém funciona apenas se colocar números inteiros ou com "." separando(15.50). Ao separar pela vírgula o cálculo já não funciona.

```js
function calcular() {
    var cpqtde = $('#cpqtde').text();
    var cpvalor = $('#cpvalor').val();
    
    $('#cpliqu').text(cpqtde * cpvalor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Quantidade:</b>
<span id="cpqtde">10</span><br>
<b>Valor:</b> <input id="cpvalor" onblur="calcular()"  type="text"><br>

<b>Resultado:</b>
<div id="cpliqu"></div>
```

Comment: Põe o código necessário para simular o problema. O que vem a ser "*a função básica*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere o `type` do `input` para `number` que passará a funcionar com `,` ou com `.` e, além disso, impossibilitará o usuário de digitar caracteres inválidos. Espero ter entendido o problema e ter ajudado.

```js
function calcular() {
    var cpqtde = $('#cpqtde').text();
    var cpvalor = $('#cpvalor').val();
    
    $('#cpliqu').text(cpqtde * cpvalor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Quantidade:</b>
<span id="cpqtde">10</span><br>
<b>Valor:</b> <input id="cpvalor" onblur="calcular()"  type="number"><br>

<b>Resultado:</b>
<div id="cpliqu"></div>
```